# JS,adding new input in array,wants to "break" if it reaches 10

Tags: javascript, arrays

Here is my code:

```
var array = []

function add() {

    var newArray = "<input type='text'>";

    array.push(newArray);
    document.getElementById("empty").innerHTML = array;

    if(array.length === 10) {
        alert("error");
    }
}
```

When i add each input by each input on my html page,it reaches 10 and alert pops up but when i close alert,i still can add more inputs,how to "break" it?
Any solutions?

Comment: So you want to stop adding new inputs when the array length reaches 10?

Comment: yeah,do you have any solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple solution from your code is

```
var newArray = "<input type='text'>";

if(array.length === 10) {
    alert("error");
}
else{
    array.push(newArray);
    document.getElementById("empty").innerHTML = array;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the Length of ur Array array before oushing the new value into it. If the value is more than 10 dont push else push.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(array.length === 10) {
    array.pop();
    alert("error");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just wrap your function in a `for` loop:

```
var array = [];

function add() {
    var newArray = "<input type='text'>";
    array.push(newArray);
    document.getElementById("empty").innerHTML = array;
}    

for (var i = 1; i <= 10, i++) {
   add();
}
```